# Multiple HTTP established connections

Tags: android, web-services, sockets, http, android-networking

Everytime a send a call to the server a different connection is established. Suppose I made three calls then when I look through `$ adb shell netstat` there are muliple instances of the server IP  at android different local ports. How can I use singleton connection for requests.

Comment: The connexion can still be kept alive server side even if it's not used android side anymore it depend how you do it